# Brightway2 : is it possible to redirect temporary files?

Tags: python, environment-variables, brightway

I wanted to know where in the configuration files (either bw2-data, -io etc.) I could find the command or the script that indicates the location of temporary files or how Bw2 chooses this location. I use a VM for applications and I don't know where BW2 puts all the files basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In Brightway

To find out where the `tempfile` library is used, you can search, e.g. [bw2data](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-data/search?q=tempfile), [bw2io](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/search?q=tempfile).

Temporary files are not used in `bw2data` (except in testing); they are only used in `bw2io` in the [function which downloads the US EEIO](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/blob/1d1c06d4b1973e2539a38f758db06143d857cdb3/bw2io/__init__.py#L131) (and in tests). The temporary directories are created in more or less at random, there is no real pattern or sense in looking for them, and the OS should automatically clean them up at some point.

## Ecoinvent Downloader (`EIDL`)

If you used the [Ecoinvent downloader](https://github.com/haasad/EcoInventDownLoader) (i.e. if you did not manually download the ecoinvent release on your own), then they do use a [temporary directory](https://github.com/haasad/EcoInventDownLoader/blob/master/eidl/core.py#L187). These are supposed to be deleted after the code completes, but if you interrupt it halfway than the delete code is never called.

## Activity Browser

The [Activity Browser](https://github.com/LCA-ActivityBrowser/activity-browser) can download files using the `EIDL`, import from an archive you have downloaded, or import from the unarchived directory of XML files. If importing from a `7z` archive, the XML files are [extracted to a temporary directory](https://github.com/LCA-ActivityBrowser/activity-browser/blob/5da4e8c1fcf84524f99b65965beba562b7c128f1/activity_browser/ui/wizards/db_import_wizard.py#L759). This directory location can't be changed without some pain, but if you are worried about storage in `/tmp`, you can extract the archive yourself to your preferred location, and then delete it whenever you choose.

Comment: I use a shared VM to run Bw2. Last time i tried to import ecoinvent, i stopped the import halfway through. The IT service told me the next day that the /tmp (directories on RAM) were full. How can I prevent this ? Do I try it again without interfering ?

Comment: Isn't it possible to write the path in the script (this one : https://github.com/haasad/EcoInventDownLoader/blob/master/eidl/core.py#L187) where I want these very temp files to be sent ?

Comment: Could be, I don't know the EIDL library, but you can always download the ecoinvent directly and put them wherever you want; EIDL is not necessary, just convenient for some.

Comment: I'm still confused, I tryna be more specific. I tried to import Ecoinvent (which I already dowloaded before import) with ActivityB, I stopped the import as I told you. Given your explanation, it's clear that I have to import it without interfering to see these temp files deleted. But I'm afraid that the directories of my VM will be full of these temp files before the import's end even so. How can I redirect them elsewhre ?

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped clarify things. I updated my answer. Ecoinvent 3.8 extracted is about 2.7 GB of data files.